# Ubuntu sound settings are getting muted upon ssh login

Tags: sound, ssh, login, pulseaudio, alsa

**Problem:** Sound settings are being muted when the first user, other than the default user, attempts to login to Ubuntu through SSH. This issue is not related to any PC fault. It occurs whenever a user, particularly the first one, logs in via SSH, causing the audio settings to be muted. Subsequent logins do not impact the audio settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Add `UsePAM no` to the file
3. `sudo service ssh restart`

[About UsePAM](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/usepam-yes-ssh-effects#:%7E:text=Advantages%20of%20Using%20UsePAM%20yes,offering%20enhanced%20security%20and%20flexibility.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! This solution seems to involve a potential tradeoff regarding security. It would be responsible to put down a sentence or two in this answer (citing some of the insights offered by the external resource), to make sure that people who use this information are clearly informed about the risks. (External links may break over time, or that content can become inaccessible in other ways.)